# What is the group term for aunt/uncle?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, hypernyms, kinship-terms

Mothers and Fathers are called parents, grandmothers and grandfathers are called grandparents, so what do you call aunts and uncles?

Comment: We just call them aunts and uncles. Anglophones in general don't tend to have or use a large stock of words defining marital and/or blood relationships.

Comment: What @FumbleFingers said. Culture doesn't translate word-for-word.

Comment: The closest I can think of would be "my parents' siblings."

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but in line with @Drew's and Fumble's comments, Robert Heinlein's novel *Citizen of the Galaxy* features a society with far MORE precise words for familial relationships (and far more cultural significance of such) than anything existing in English.  A good read.

Comment: _Zeroth cousin once-removed_. Of course, this would also be what you called your nieces and nephews.

Comment: If it is of any help Chinese has very precise names for every possible extended relative. There would even be a word for "my mother's third older sister's husband", and one quite different to "my father's older brother". English would call them both "uncle" - but not in Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard "**extended family**" used for this. Merriam-Webster even has an entry for it:

> - a family that includes in one household near relatives (such as grandparents, aunts, or uncles) in addition to a nuclear family

Though that might be more inclusive than you're looking for.

Comment: "Extended family" would also include cousins, grandchildren, an probably some more distant relatives.